# Who had the contract in the abandoned shack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the [Dark Brotherhood mission](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:With_Friends_Like_These...) where you have to kill one of the three people in the room: [the Khajiit guy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vasha) who was pretty cool, [the mercenary](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fultheim_the_Fearless) who was pleading and [a woman](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alea_Quintus) who was running her mouth at me. I killed the woman in the end.

Who actually had the contract?

Comment: I don't think there is a right choice. I killed all three without any consequence. Maybe they all had a contract on their head, or none of them. It doesn't mattered to my character...

Comment: I don't care about concequences I just want to know

Comment: The correct way of showing users your appreciation is by [up voting and accepting their answers (to your questions)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47117/how-to-spot-an-imminent-dragon-attack). Thanking users by showing "thank you" in a question just makes it harder for other users to find your question, and reduces the readability of your question.

Comment: Well I'll just than shadow wizard in a comment

Comment: Comments are nice. Upvotes and accepts are *nicer*.

Comment: Can I ask why everyone's so serious on this show, seriously everyone edits my stuff and tells me off...

Comment: @CHARLO: Editing each other's Q&A's is standard fare here (don't take it personally); it makes everything neater and more useful to future people reading them. The criticism is usually just friendly advice: They're just trying to help you to understand the site's community.

Answer (score 21):

While it's almost certain they all had contracts out on them, Astrid does prefer you killing one particular person over the others:

> Vasha, the Khajit, describes himself as a murderer, a rapist, and a thief. If you kill him, Astrid remarks that he was the obvious choice.

However, if you kill all of them, she'll make a snarky comment that you're an overachiever.

But as you'll soon find out—should you choose to join the Dark Brotherhood—the contracts placed are, many times, non-obvious and counterintuitive.

Basically,  the point of the abandoned shack test is to get you to kill on command: if the Family says someone needs to die, that person needs to die, regardless of what excuse they give you or backstory they have.

Comment: I always took that remark from Astrid as being a bit sardonic. She's not telling you you've chosen *well*, but rather, that you've chosen *easily*.  +1 for the real point of the whole thing however.

Comment: It doesn't matter that much, as I brutally murdered the woman for running her mouth at me

Comment: I believe if you talk to the people in the dark brotherhood they mention about Astrid doing that type of initiation and something about all of them being innocent. She asked you to pick one to kill, you did.. That was the contract, your choice :)

Comment: Just because one of the ways Vasha describes himself is as a defiler of daughters doesn't necessarily mean he's a rapist. Khajiit can be smooth talkers and potentially interesting to a young lady(read the Real Barenziah series of books in the game. Volume 2 in particular I think). He may smooth talk young unmarried ladies into loosing their virtue with him, making the family out for blood when they find out(particularly if the are ultra racist nords).

Answer (score 15):

If you use the Clairvoyance illusion spell, it leads you to the Khajiit. Whether it's because he's the real contract, or if he just happens to be were the "location marker" of the quest is, I don't know. I would expect it to be him, or the Mercenary. The woman would makes sense too, as stated above the reasons for contracts are sometimes quite petty and ridiculous. I always choose the Khajiit. Not only does he threaten you (if you don't let him go), but he talks about all the *disgusting* actions he's been apart of.

I would say that it doesn't matter who has the contract. You aren't meant to know, so as in a real life situation such as this, might as well kill the one you THINK it is and keep a peaceful state of mind by believing you were right.

Comment: Very clever with the Clairvoyance spell, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 9):

After I killed one of the targets I asked Astrid if I made the right choice. She said it didn't matter which one I choose, the test was to see if I could kill someone in cold blood.

You never get to know who had a contract or who didn't. As Jupotter already commented, they all probably had a contract on their head. That becomes pretty clear after doing a few contracts for the dark brotherhood; people want to see other people dead for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: Yes but I want to see some people's choices and reasons for doing so

Comment: @CHARLO Gaming.SE isn't a discussion site. We aren't here to talk about various peoples choices and reasons for doing things, we're here to *answer questions*. You might want to check out the FAQ.

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to narrow it down I want to know by asking questions hence QUESTIONS

Comment: Reason for killing any of the victims is simple. You have to do it to join dark brotherhood

Answer (score -1):

I personally think the contract's on her, since apparently when you kill her, she says 'well done.' (I've never killed her but that's what the wiki says.)

Comment: +1 for Randomname's answer. I actually killed her with my first char because I couldn't bring myself to kill any of the three hostages...even the cranky lady haha.

Comment: She doesn't have a contract on her - whenever you kill her you fail the dark brotherhood membership quest and instead begin a quest to destroy the dark brotherhood.  There's no reason that the dark brotherhood would put a contract on one of their senior members - the "well done" is more a gesture of congratulations on not getting sucked into the dark brotherhood

Comment: @DaveMcClelland Actually, SPOILER ALERT